# jquerymobile href links not visibiel with phonegap on android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, attr

I am building a phonegap based mobileweb application which is built almost completely with jquerymobile.

In couple of pages, there are links to external sites and the client wants to show a popup asking if the user is willing to leave the app and go to the external site. Client also asked that the application shall exit if the user chooses to follow the link.

Here is my JS:

```
if (typeof CORP == "undefined" || !CORP) {
  var CORP = {};
}

(function() {
      CORP.mk = {
            var mobile = false;
            init: function() {
                        $("[data-role='page']").on("pagebeforeshow", CORP.mk.setHandlers);
            },
            onDeviceReady: function () {
                  CORP.mk.mobile = true;
                  document.addEventListener("pause", CORP.mk.onPause, false);
            },
            onPause: function () { // Exit the app if it goes to background
                  navigator.app.exitApp();
           },
          setHandlers: function () {
             if ( CORP.mk.mobile ) {
                    $("a[rel='external']").click(function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        CORP.mk.externalLink = $(this).attr("href");
                        alert(CORP.mk.externalLink);
                        navigator.notification.confirm("You are about to close this mobile app and open your web browser.",
                                            CORP.mk.popupConfirm,
                                            "Close This App?");
                    });
             }
          }
      };
})():
$(document).bind("pageinit", CORP.mk.init);
document.addEventListener("deviceready", CORP.mk.onDeviceReady, false);
```

Here is my markup:

```
<a rel='external' data-ajax='false' href='http://www.google.com'>googly</a>
```

Problem: I tested this code ignoring `CORP.mk.mobile` on chrome desktop browser and it works fine. However `$(this).attr("href");` always returns `'#'` for the `href` in `Android` or `IOS` and I cannot launch external application with phonegap. I want to be able to get the actual link and launch external app. I tried many combinations and couldn't find a solution. Appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue. This is happening due to `e.preventDefault();` which is replacing the link. I am surprised that this doesn't happen in desktop browsers.. 
So, instead of

```
e.preventDefault();
CORP.mk.externalLink = $(this).attr("href");
```

I need to do

```
CORP.mk.externalLink = $(this).attr("href");
e.preventDefault();
```